# Error: [$compile:tpload] when running in debug mode in android devices

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ngcordova

### I have used $location.path in my cordova application

I am having cordova application with angularjs. I have successfully loggedIn to the dashboard page.

When I am clicking the events and the organization tabs, I am getting error for some specific pages having the `$location.path('')` for all the tabs.

$location.path is working properly when I am using it in browser platform, but getting

> Error: [$compile:tpload] when running in debug mode in android devices.

```
$scope.aboutus = function () {
    $location.path("/aboutus");
}

$scope.notifications = function () {
   $location.path("/notifications");
}

$scope.cardHolderPage = function () {
   $location.path("/cardHolderPage");
}

$scope.getOwnCard = function () {
    $location.path('/ownCards');
}
$scope.getEvents = function () {
    $location.path("/events");
}
$scope.getOrganizations = function () {
   $location.path('/organizations');
}
```

$scope.aboutus() and $scope.contactus() functions are working, but getEvents() and getOrganizations() is working, giving errors:

> Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: views/loggedIn/VisitingCard/createVisitingCard.html (HTTP status: -1 )
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$compile/tpload?p0=views%2FloggedIn%2FVisitingCard%2FcreateVisitingCard.html&p1=-1&p2=
>
> ```
> Error: $templateRequest:tpload
> Error Loading Template
> ```
>
> Failed to load template: views/loggedIn/VisitingCard/createVisitingCard.html (HTTP status: -1 )

### RouteConfig.js

```
myApp.config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
       when("/aboutus", {
            templateUrl: "views/LoggedIn/AboutUs/aboutus.html",
            controller: "DashboardController"
        }).when("/notifications", {
            templateUrl: "views/loggedIn/Notification/notifications.html",
            controller: "NotificationController"
        }).when("/events", {
            templateUrl: "views/loggedIn/Events/events.html",
            controller: "ViewEventController"
        }).when("/organizations", {
            templateUrl: "./views/loggedIn/Organizations/viewOrganizations.html",
            controller: "ViewOrganizationController"
        }).when("/cardHolderPage", {
            templateUrl: "views/loggedIn/CardHolders/cardHolder.html",
            controller: "CardHolderController"
        })
}])
```

### Html Page

```
<li class="list-group-item clickable" ng-if="premium_status == 'Premium'">
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" ng-click="getOrganizations()">
        <i class="far fa-building"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Organization
    </a>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item clickable" ng-if="premium_status == 'Premium'">
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" ng-click="getEvents()">
        <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Event
    </a>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item clickable" ng-if="premium_status != 'Premium'">
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" ng-click="premium()">
        <i class="fa fa-th"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Go Premium!
    </a>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item clickable">
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" ng-click="aboutus()">
        <i class="far fa-address-card"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; About Us
    </a>
</li>
```

I just want to route it to the another page.

Comment: See [AngularJS Error Reference - tpload](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$templateRequest/tpload)

Comment: Status -1 often indicates a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) problem.

Comment: AngularJs Error Reference - tpload link I have checked and I have also checked the misspell of the route and it is correct.